# jsoup java.net.UnknownHostException while trying Jsoup.connect(''any url'')

Tags: java, android, jsoup, ioexception

Im trying to run this piece of code

```
            String test;
            Document doc= null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http:\\thatsthefinger.com\\").get();
                test=doc.title();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                out.setText(e.getMessage());
            }
```

this is the execption im getting.

```
W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: http:\thatsthefinger.com\
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createAddress(HttpEngine.java:1143)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:323)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:249)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:652)
W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:629)
W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:261)
W/System.err:     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:250)
W/System.err:     at gplabs.szalpha.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:62)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21177)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
W/System.err:     at     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

I searched everywhere and did everything i could, but couldn't solve.
Anyone at least give me a working piece of code to it on my version of android studio, because i doubt my avm.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your url correct?

Comment: yeah. even if i replace any url with it, it does the same.

Comment: Do you have permission for internet in manifest?

Comment: i did add the <uses-permission.................INTERNET> thing to the manifest also.

Comment: There much guessing here. Are you using emulator or real android device? Did you check internet connection on your device is it low or weak?

Comment: Hey there. great!. i found a thing now. even if i turn the data off and try the code. it produces the exact error. but i did add the internet permission to manifest. is there a way to figure out the error?

Comment: im using real device. im using the same internet connection from the device to write this comment.

Comment: If you are using wifi try mobile data and vice versa

Comment: Did you put permission for internet in right place in application tag in Manifest?

Comment: You didn't copy that URL from /to an actual browser did you? The slashes are the wrong direction

Comment: I'll try changing the slashes and let you know soon.

Comment: I have updated my answer for your requirement. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Write it like this

connect("http://www.thatsthefinger.com")

Comment: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
                                                                  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
                                                                  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
                                                                  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215) ......it goes like this

Comment: @PoomaniGP first of all you said you tried another urls and they also don't work but seems your error was obvious second one you can't download data from internet on UI thread you have to run it in background for example use `AsyncTask`

Comment: @Yupi i did use many other urls and everytime i made the same mistake of using 'backslash', secondly i thought of using the AsyncTask but instead i ran a thread to check if it works and it does, anyways thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

as Vedvrat said. See at this line your URL is wrong.

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: http:\thatsthefinger.com\
```

You have to pass valid URL. Url must be: http://www.thatsthefinger.com

That doesn't give you a new issue `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Actually, you are not allowed to call network operations in MainThread. If it is allowed, The main thread has to wait until the result comes. Result, Your app will stay hanged until the result comes. It will produce bad user experience.

Use AsyncTask to call network operations.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Document> {
     protected Document doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Document doc= null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http:\\thatsthefinger.com\\").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            out.setText(e.getMessage());
        }
        return doc;
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Document doc) {
         if(doc != null){
            String test= doc.title();
         }
     }
 }
```

See here for more info about AsyncTask: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html